# There is no one we have to wait. / We have no one else to wait for

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I'm trying to translate this sentence from my native language. Please, see the following versions:

1. **We have no one to wait anymore.** (That's my online teacher version. I think, it's not correct. I can't see something similar on the internet.)
2. **We have no one else to wait for.** (That's google translate version. Is it natural?)
3. **There is no one we have to wait.** (That's my version. I suppose, it's not necessary to add "for" after "wait" because we have no object after verb "wait".)

Which version is more common and natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always need the "for". The two versions without it are simply incorrect.

The Google version is fine, if a little formal. You might say:

> We don't have anyone else to wait for.

Comment: Could you say, please, the third one is good with "for"? **There is no one we have to wait for.** I'm trying to understand and feel English without Google.

Comment: Yes that would be fine.

Comment: Also the first version could be fine with "... to wait **for** anymore."